# Xamarin Forms Rotated ListView Spins on Redraw

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

To make a chat page, I followed an example I found that sets the ListView rotation to 180, so the list builds from the bottom and then set things in the DataTemplate to rotate 180, so the items will be upright. It's a great solution, but when the keyboard opens, the ListView gets shorter which causes a redraw. During the redraw, the ListView initially appears with rotation 0 and I see an animation as if RotateTo(360) is being called. After initially displaying, I get to watch the list view rotate around in full circle. Click off the message editor, and the ListView gets taller, and it does it again.
Has anyone seen this?

Here's what the Xaml looks like. I can't make a gif of what it looks like, but imagine watching:

```
MessageList.Rotation = 0;
MessageList.RotateTo(360, 500, Easing.Linear);
```

each time the keyboard shows and hides, and you'll get the idea...

```
<ListView
    X:Name="MessageList"
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
    Rotation="180"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ChatMessages}"
    SelectionMode="None"
    HasUnevenRows="True" 
    SeparatorColor="Transparent">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Frame
                    BackgroundColor="LightGray"
                    FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
                    Rotation="180"
                    Padding="10"
                    HasShadow="false"
                    Margin="80,2,0,5">
                        <Label Text="{Binding ChatText}"/>
                </Frame>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Can you please share us a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? And in my opinion, you probably can't avoid the rotation when the keyboard opens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I wound up doing was to make a custom ListView renderer that was keyboard aware in iOS and sets a translation X to move the top of the listview up when the keyboard appears and back down when it goes away. As a result, the listview is not getting resized, and thus does not redraw.

It may be messy, but it makes it work...

Answer (score 1):

I followed the same tutorial you mentioned and you are probably using a ContentPage renderer to handle your keyboard layout updates on iOS. If you check the sample project https://github.com/rdelrosario/ChatUIXForms you'll notice he resizes the keyboard ContentView with a ContentView renderer for the Editor box at the bottom using the Margin property, rather than the entire ContentPage. Which doesn't trigger the above issue.